# Determine all open sets on which $f$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Given $$f(z) = \frac{1}{x} + i(-\frac{1}{y})$$
>   Determine all open sets in which $f$ is analytic.

**My attempt:**

$$f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$$
where $u(x,y) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $v(x,y) = -\frac{1}{y}$

Now, consider the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

Firstly, \begin{align}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0 = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = - (0) = 0\end{align}

Hence, we know $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} =-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ holds for all (nonzero) $x,y$.

However,

\begin{align}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &\iff -\frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{y^2} \\ &\iff -x^2 = y^2 \\ &\iff y = \pm ~xi\end{align}
However, $y = \pm ~xi$ does not form an open set, hence $f$ is **not** analytic on any open subset of $\mathbb C$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Pedant alert: $\varnothing$!

Comment: @DanielFischer - Haha! Thank you :). I'm sorry for asking so many questions on here. I don't have a very good reference book, so I just rather post some attempts on here to make sure I am on the right track :).

Answer (score 1):

$x$ and $y$ are real, so $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ means $(x,y) = (0,0)$. Thus if $f$ is analytic on an open $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, then $U \subseteq \{(0,0)\}$. This forces $U = \varnothing$.